# web3py - Sending a transaction to a payable contract function

Tags: contract-invocation, web3.py

I have deployed a smart contract dthat contains a payable function `fundit(address _to)`. Now I am trying to use a `Contract` object to send ether to the function:

```py
tx_hash = instance.fundit.sendTransaction(instance2.address, {"from": w3.eth.accounts[0], "value": 1})
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
'Contract' object has no attribute 'fundit'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What are `instance` and `instance2` in your example code? Which version of `web3py` are you using?

Comment: @goodvibration web3py version 5.4.0.

Comment: @iamdefinitelyahuman Thank you. Instance is the Smart Contract deployed having the function fundit(address payable to) public payable {}.
Instance2 is another deployed contract where I want the donation to be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `instance` is a [`Contract`](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract) object, classes for calling contract functions are found inside the [`Contract.function`](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract.functions) member. The correct syntax for what you wish to do is:

```py
contract_function = instance.functions.fundit(instance2.address)
tx_hash = contract_function.transact({"from": w3.eth.accounts[0], "value": 1})
```

1. In the first line, you invoke the [`ContractFunction`](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.ContractFunction) with the inputs you wish to use in the transaction.
2. In the second line, you call the [`ContractFunction.transact`](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.ContractFunction.transact) method to perform the transaction. The only argument should be a [transaction dictionary](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.sendTransaction).

You can of course merge these two lines into one, I only separated them to make the example easier to read.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly!!
I have another question, how can you do this for ConciseContract?

Comment: `concise_instance.fundit(instance2.address, transact={"from": w3.eth.accounts[0], "value": 1})` should do it.

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: you might also consider Brownie, which has a significantly less verbose API for contract interaction - https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interaction.html#accessing-contract-methods

Comment: Thank you so much! I am quite new to this but I will surely take a look. :)